# Overriding values in sub-charts in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have used nginx-ingress controller as a sub-chart and I want to override controller.service.nodePorts.http in the subchart. I tried few things and nothing seem to work. Here is what I've tried

- using --set controller.service.nodePorts.http=32080 during helm install command
- declaring this path in my chart's value.yaml

I've also gone over the helm documentation for overriding sub-chart values but none seem to work.

Any points what I may be missing ? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6):

When overriding values of a sub-chart, you need to nest those configurations under the name of the subchart. For example in values.yaml:

```
mysubchart:
  x: y
```

In your case, if you imported the nginx controller chart as `nginx-controller`, you could add this to the main chart:

```
nginx-controller:
  controller:
    service:
      nodePorts:
        http: "32080"
```

This topic is covered in the helm docs under: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md#overriding-values-of-a-child-chart

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the solution mentioned but it still does not work.

I checked the name of the chart it is nginx-ingress, but updating that in the values.yaml also does not set the value of the controller.


I also checked the command :

helm install --dry-run --debug mychart

the value in the output is updated but when I do helm install it does not reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be different from the original case, but still might be helpful to someone facing a similar problem.
It might be an issue with specifying a value.

In my case I had a subchart "subchartName" with a misleading value "{{ .Values.subchartName.path }}". The value is defined in subchart values as:

```
subchartName:
  path: 123
```

So in the parent chart values.yaml the value should be specified as:

```
subchartName:
  subchartName:
    path: 321
```

helm template . -f parent-values.yaml will give the expected result then.